# Importing class-type global variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a configuration system contained within a module. The core configuration variable is a class instance and a global variable in this module. It seems that when I import this variable, I cannot use it as a class for some reason.

Consider this minimal example:

### foomodule.py:

```
class FooClass:
    number = 5

    def bar (self):
        return self.number

foo = FooClass
foo.number = 5
```

### main.py

```
from foomodule import foo
print foo.bar()
```

Running main.py results in a cryptic error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print foo.bar()
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with FooClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

But I am calling it with a FooClass instance which I'd think should be the `self` argument like it usually is. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only bound `foo` to the *class*; you didn't make it an instance:

```
foo = FooClass  # only creates an additional reference
```

Call the class:

```
foo = FooClass()  # creates an instance of FooClass
```

In Python you usually don't use accessor methods; just reference `foo.number` in your `main` module, rather than use `foo.bar()` to obtain it.

Comment: That's funky. With local variables the former does not appears to cause problems. How come only imported variables fret out like this? Also foo.bar() is an accessor since it's an example, my real use cases are larger than this.

Comment: @crimsondusk: this has **nothing** to do with importing. If you only imported the class you'd still have to call it to create an instance.

Comment: @crimsondusk: take into account that python literals (creating strings, integers, lists, etc.) tell the Python compiler to call the type for you; `foo.number = 5` tells Python to create an instance of the `int` type for you. But there is no 'literal syntax' to create instances of custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `foo` is just an alias for `FooClass`. I assume that your actual problem is more complicated than your snippet. However, if you really need a class method, you can annotate it with `@classmethod` decorator.

```
class FooClass(object):
    number = 5

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        return cls.number
```

To use your the class you could do:

```
from foomodule import Foo
Foo.bar()
```

Or you can access the class member directly

```
Foo.number
```